# La chaleur et le chaud, la difference

Tags: vocabulaire

Pourrais-t-on expliquer la différence entre **chaleur** et **chaud** (nom) ?

Je ne sais pas dans quel contexte je dois les utiliser.

Lequel est le plus utilisé ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le mot « chaleur » est dans son sens le plus fondamental un concept de la physique qui est associé à une quantité d'énergie de la matière et à plusieurs grandeurs physiques<sup>1</sup>, en particulier la température. Il n'existe pas d'opposé. Ce n'est pas seulement un terme scientifique mais c'est aussi le terme que l'on utilise pour nommer ce qui produit une sensation opposée à celle du froid dans tout ce que l'on touche; cependant on l'appelle aussi « le chaud » dans certains cas;

> Mettez-vous sous la couverture; dès que vous commencez à sentir (le chaud/la chaleur) baissez le thermostat à la température voulue.

Dans son sens important de « saison » le mot « chaleur » a un opposé; « **la chaleur** » ou « **la saison chaude** » sont des termes que l'on utilise pour une période de l'année incluant l'été, la fin du printemps et le début de l'automne;  « le froid » ou « la saison froide » sont des termes que l'on utilise pour l'hiver, la fin de l'automne, le début du printemps.

On dit « **les premiers froids** » mais pas « les premiers chauds »; il faut dire « **les premières chaleurs** »; il s'agit respectivement des premières journées froides (chaudes) de la saison froide (chaude).

[On dit moins](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mourir+de+chaud%2Cmourir+de+chaleur&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmourir%20de%20chaud%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmourir%20de%20chaleur%3B%2Cc0) « **mourir de chaud** » que « **mourir de chaleur** » et cela qu'il soit question de la chaleur due à l'été ou à celle d'un intérieur surchauffé.

Dans l'expression courante « **rester au chaud** », « le chaud » signifie « l'intérieur chauffé d'une habitation »; il existe un opposé, le froid, et il s'agit alors de l'extérieur des habitations surtout en hiver et à la fin de l'automne ou au début du printemps et il s'agit aussi de parties intérieures non chauffées pendant la saison froide. « **Ne restez pas au froid.** » signifie « Tenez-vous au chaud, à l'intérieur, où il fait chaud. ». On ne dit pas « [rester à la chaleur](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rester+au+chaud%2Crester+%C3%A0+la+chaleur&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crester%20au%20chaud%3B%2Cc0) ».

Dans les expressions courantes « **tenir (garder) quelque chose au chaud** », lorsque le quelque chose en question est un plat « le chaud » signifie « la chaleur de l'intérieur chauffé d'un four ou d'une plaque chauffante ».

On dit très très peu « [tenir à la chaleur](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tenir+%C3%A0+la+chaleur%2Ctenir+au+chaud&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctenir%20%C3%A0%20la%20chaleur%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctenir%20au%20chaud%3B%2Cc0) »; on dit presque seulement « **tenir au chaud** ».

En parlant des robinets d'eau chaude et d'eau froide d'un lavabo ou plutôt de nos jours du sens dans lequel actionner le mélangeur on dit « **le chaud** » et « **le froid** », ce qui signifie « le robinet (sens) de l'eau chaude » (ou « robinet d'eau chaude ») et « le robinet de l'eau froide »; dans cet usage particulier s'est produite une nominalisation de l'adjectif « chaude » avec une association de genre selon le genre du mot « robinet » (ou « sens »).

Dans les expression « **avoir chaud** », « **faire chaud** » et « **tenir chaud** », « chaud » est un adverbe.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>correction de l'initial « la chaleur est une grandeur physique » due à aCOSwt 

NON! : La chaleur n'est pas une grandeur physique. En tant que grandeur physique dans le domaine, je ne connais que la température, la quantité de chaleur, le flux de chaleur, la chaleur massique, la chaleur latente, certains peuvent y adjoindre la chaleur sensible s'ils veulent mais de chaleur tout-court... connais pas! – 
Quant à la "chaleur, élément physique"... aux temps dans lesquels vous vous trouvez manifestement... c'est le bûcher qui vous guette...</sub>

Comment: **NON!** : La *chaleur* n'est pas une *grandeur physique*. En tant que *grandeur physique* dans le domaine, je ne connais que la **température**, la **quantité de chaleur**, le **flux de chaleur**, la **chaleur massique**, la **chaleur latente**, certains peuvent y adjoindre la **chaleur sensible** s'ils veulent mais de chaleur tout-court... connais pas!

Comment: Quant à la *"chaleur, élément physique"*... aux temps dans lesquels vous vous trouvez manifestement... c'est le bûcher qui vous guette... jdiçajdirien!

Comment: Than k you .. !